# why is this if statement not doing anything?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Believe me the HTML won't be necessary on this one since the if statement only deals with the cBox variable. What this does is, create or close a div upon clicking a button, i've tested the functions and they work, what's not working however is the way these functions are called, I've logged the outputs but i get neither of them displayed in the console, this means the code is not running through the if statement for some reason.

Also tried with `if (cBox == null)` and it doesn't work ...

```
btnPress.onclick = function formConfirm() {
    var cBox = document.getElementById('cBox');
    console.log(" but cbox is "+cBox);
    if(cBox) {
        closecBox();
        console.log("cbox exists, closing ...");
    } else {
        opencBox();
        console.log("cbox does not exist, creating...");
    }
};
```

Comment: `this means the code is not running through the if statement for some reason.` That's correct. As to why it's not running we have no idea. What's `btnPress`?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand... you're getting the "but cbox is..." log, but not either of the "exists" or "does not exist"?

Comment: Perhaps the code is breaking inside of `closecBox` or `opencBox`, are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Have you tried moving the `console.log` statements to the line *before* you call `closecBox` or `opencBox`? Perhaps something is breaking in those methods.

Comment: If you're not seeing any console logs at all, I suspect a form which submits to the current page is being used, and `btnPress` is a submit button, and nothing stops the event. Thus, the form submits and page reloads, emptying the console of whatever had made it there.

Comment: This is not dealing only with `cBox` but also with `btnPress` so HTML (and some other Javascript) is for sure relevant.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this in a browser JavaScript debugger? You can stick a breakpoint right before the If statement that you expect to be entered and see whether the variables are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/f6Pw8/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i understand your question but if your code is like this seems to work [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/4TvDy/)

```
function closeBox(elem){
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        }
    function openBox(el){
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.setAttribute("id", "cBox");
        document.body.appendChild(el);
        }   

    var btnPress = document.getElementById('button');

    btnPress.onclick = function formConfirm() {
        var cBox = document.getElementById('cBox');
        if(cBox) {
            closeBox(cBox)
            console.log("cbox exists, closing ...");
        } else {
            openBox(cBox);
            console.log("cbox does not exist, creating...");
        }
    };
```

If i did not understand your question sorry for having done wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you for all the replies, your hints were definitely helpful for solving this problem, i made so many changes that i lost track but this is the working code

```
var btnPress = document.getElementById('theBtn');
btnPress.onclick = function formConfirm() {
    var cBox = document.getElementById('confirmBox');
        console.log("cbox is "+cBox);  
    if(cBox) {
        console.log("cbox exists, closing ...");
        closecBox();
    } else {
        opencBox();
        console.log("cbox does not exist, creating...");
    }
};

function opencBox() {
    var cBox = document.createElement('div');
    cBox.id = "confirmBox";
    document.body.appendChild(cBox);
    cBox.style.display="inline";
};

function closecBox() {
    var cBox = document.getElementById('confirmBox');
    cBox.style.display="none";
    document.body.removeChild(cBox);
};
```

I also used display style to test some other stuff with animations :) once again, thank you so much for all the comments! They really helped me out figuring the solution!